# How can i make exception treatment cleaner?

Tags: java, jpa, exception

I am working with JPA and need to threat the same exception multiple times in my code, is there way to make this cleaner or am i doing it right?

```
public long getNumCategorias(int ejercicio) {
    try{
        return  (long) em.createNativeQuery(
            "SELECT count(id_categoria) AS num_categorias FROM ruepep.categorias WHERE categoria_padre IS NULL AND ejercicio = " + ejercicio)
            .getSingleResult();
    }catch(NoResultException e){
        return 0;
    }
}

public long getNumSubCategorias(int ejercicio) {
    try{
        return  (long) em.createNativeQuery(
            "SELECT count(id_categoria) AS num_categorias FROM ruepep.categorias WHERE categoria_padre IS NOT NULL AND ejercicio = " + ejercicio)
            .getSingleResult();
    }catch(NoResultException e) {
        return 0;
    }
}

public Categoria getCategoria(int id) {
    try {
        return (Categoria) em.createNamedQuery("Categoria.GetById").setParameter("id", id).getSingleResult();
    }catch(NoResultException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I think it makes the code kind of harder to read

Comment: Looks fine to me. If you were returning the same type/value each time after catching the exception, there could be a way to generalise it with a lambda, but IMO the code seems to be in its simplest form

Comment: I dont know the whole implementation but there is a chance that, in large codebases, it is a problem to sometimes return 0/default and sometimes null. Otherwise I think your exception handling is fine

Answer (score 0):

**Spring Boot** introduced a concept called **Controller-Advice** to handle exceptions in one class

```
@ControllerAdvice
@ResponseBody
public class RestControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public ApiError handleException(Exception ex) {
        return buildErrorResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ex);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public ApiError handleValidationExceptions(
            MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
        ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach((error) -> {
            String fieldName = ((FieldError) error).getField();
            String errorMessage = error.getDefaultMessage();
            errors.put(fieldName, errorMessage);
        });
        return buildErrorResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, errors, ex);
    }
}
```

when you throw Exception like

`throw new MethodArgumentNotValidException("method not valid")`

**handleValidationException** method catch it

similary you can do same with **custom-exceptions**

Comment: I looks a bit overcomplicated for me at the moment, also im using Tomcat so i wont be able to implementit but ty for the help anyways :))